Trouble calculating Weil-Peterson volumes recursively
I am having some trouble calculating Weil-Peterson volumes using Mirzakhani's recursion, following [1]. Taking $V_{0,1}(L1)$ = 0, $V_{1,2} (L1, L2) = 0$ and $V_{0,3}(L1, L2, L3) = 1$ as the base cases, they state the recursion relations as follows:

The Weil–Petersson volumes satisfy the following equation for $2g + n > 3$:
\begin{align}
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial L_1} L_1 V_{g,n}(L) 
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty xy H(x + y, L_1) V_{g-1,n+1}(x, y, \hat{L}) \, dx \, dy
\\
&+ \sum_{\substack{g_1 + g_2 = g \\ I \sqcup J = \{2, \ldots, n\}}} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty xy H(x + y, L_1) V_{g_1,|I|+1}(x, L_I) V_{g_2,|J|+1}(y, L_J) \, dx \, dy
\\
&+ \sum_{k=2}^n \int_0^\infty x \left[ H(x, L_1 + L_k) + H(x, L_1 - L_k) \right] V_{g,n-1}(x, \hat{L}_k) \, dx
\end{align}
Here, we have used the notation $\hat{L} = (L_2, L_3, \ldots, L_n)$, $L_I = (L_{i_1}, L_{i_2}, \ldots, L_{i_m})$ for $I = \{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_m\}$, and $\hat{L}_k = (L_2, \ldots, \hat{L}_k, \ldots, L_n)$, where the hat denotes omission. The function $H : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$
H(x, y) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)} + \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}.
$$

This is mostly fine, and my calculations match Appendix B of [1] for $g\leq1$. However, I am having some trouble with $g=2, n=0$.
In this case, the only contribution should be from the first term, involving $V_{1,1}$:
\begin{align}
2 \frac{\partial}{\partial L_1} L_1 V_{g,n}(L) 
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty xy H(x + y, L_1) V_{1,1}(x) \, dx \, dy
\end{align}
However, naively following their procedure yields
$$
V_{2,0} = \frac{L_1^6}{80640} + \frac{\pi^2 L_1^4}{1440} + \frac{17\pi^4 L_1^2}{2160} + \frac{4\pi^6}{189}
$$
which does not match [1]. I am a bit unsure how to approach this, especially how to remove the dependence on $L_1$? Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.
References

[1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4674
